# Mongodb/mongoose aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have below data in mongodb:

```
{
  "articleId": 1,  
  "QuliatyScore": 80,
  "RelvanceToTech": 50,
  "FeedbackAuthor":"Jack"  
},
{
  "articleId": 1,  
  "QualityScore": 80,
  "RelvanceToTech": 50,
  "FeedbackAuthor":"Tom"  
},
{
  "articleId": 2,  
  "QualityScore": 60,
  "RelvanceToTech": 30,
  "FeedbackAuthor":"Jack"  
},
{
  "articleId": 2,  
  "QualityScore": 70,
  "RelvanceToTech": 40,
  "FeedbackAuthor":"Tom"  
}
```

....

I would like to get top 3 average score (select top 3 Avg(QualityScore+FeedbackAuthor) article from all authors

Comment: Is that top three articles with the highest average QualityScore or top three authors with highest average QualityScore or something else? Try to form a more clear question.

Comment: Hi, I would like to get top three articles with the highest average score (Qualityscore+RelvanceToTech)

Comment: Then update your question to make it helpful for other readers. You have Avg(QualityScore+FeedbackAuthor) in your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the aggregate query (tested on MongoDB 3.0):

```
[  
   {  
      $project:{  
         articleId:"$articleId",
         score:{  
            $add:[  
               "$QualityScore",
               "$RelevanceToTech"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      $group:{  
         _id:"$articleId",
         avgScore:{  
            $avg:"$score"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      $sort:{  
         avgScore:-1
      }
   },
   {  
      $limit:3
   }
]
```

Explanation:

1. **$project**: In the project stage the two columns you want to average their sums are added together and projected as "score". Plus the articleId which you will need to group.
2. **$group**: group by the articleId and average by "score" which was calculated in $project stage.
3. **$sort**: Sort by "avgScore" in descending order.
4. **$limit**: Return the first 3 results. Since the results are descending ordered by avgScore this effectively returns the top 3 articles with the highest average of your sum.